# Make {{!LOOP}} jump or replace by Content ID in iMacros

Tags: imacros, webautomation

I have problems with making `!LOOP` jump Content Id  each time instead of +1

I want make  imacros jump Id  Like this

Above sample goes to `icccy1@in.com`,`icccy2@in.com`,`icccy3@in.com` instead of `ironman@in.com`, `starktower@mail.com`,`Fernaf@gmail.com`

Here is my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !VAR1 100

SET !LOOP {{!VAR1}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolder2_txtUserID CONTENT=icccy1{{!VAR1}}@in.com
```

Running this still makes iMacros jump +1 each loop.

Comment: I am novice please don't lock me

Comment: It seems like you want to test for a range of user ids, you'll have to pull these values from a datasource.  Look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859005/imacros-concatenating-strings-from-datasource?answertab=active#tab-top) example.  Essentially you set your datasource line to be the {{!LOOP}} value, then you will pull in the corresponding value to put in your tag CONTENT variable.

Comment: how to make datasource ?

Comment: Please Teach me how to do it ??

Comment: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getIntPref], line 4 (Error code: -1001)